# XmlSerialization: Questions about performance & References

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I've to come with a technical proposal to serialize a large set of object into an XML. We currently have a database with NHibernate

It's not really the point, but since I already that it will be your first question:

**Why XML**

- We have a very particular need: We have a lot of data, but we only use them once sometimes, to configure a lot of hardware devices on the network. Meaning that when we need the data, we read the whole database
- We are currently using NHibernate, and we have the impression that due to complex class structure, it takes a lot of times to serialize/deserialize data.
- We have a lot hierarchical levels, and it takes a lot of time to make joins
- We often have to change the structure, an XSLT would fit perfectly our upgrade needs
- We want to avoid a third party library(licensing + distribution issue)

So now, I'm thinking on what would be the best way to serialize those data.

I'm aware of the `XmlSerializer` class, but for what I understood, it works by reflection, getting all the properties, checking if there is any decorator on method/properties, and I'm concerned about having performance issue.

I'm also worried about references: we have a root object, and a leaf can reference another leaf(like: Root node A, which owns a B and C object, and C reference B(very dummy example, in our case we have a lot of levels/abstraction between).

1. Am I right about the reflection usage with the `XmlSerializer` ? Is there a way to avoid Reflection(Other than implementing `IXmlSerializable`?
2. How do you handle those objects referenced twice(and if you only serialize one reference, is there a way to restore the other reference?

Comment: I would just use `XDocument` / `XElement`.

Comment: Every serializer needs to know about a set of fields on a type.  The only way to do that in general is to use reflection, or provide an interface (`ISerializable`, `IXmlSerializable`) that defers the serialization to the user.

Comment: The exception would be when you are writing a serializer, purpose-built to serialize a particular object graph, and not a generalized serializer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Do you have an example of utilisation with an object that owns another object?

Comment: @SteveGuidi Agreed, but now I've to define how. I don't want to use  ÌXmlSerializable` because we would have xml concerns put in business objects. I'm looking to a way to be a little bit more generic(like having a method to implement, and registering method that can be used to get/set my serialized values)

Comment: See my answer below. It's not great, but shows how you can compose XML from sub-serializers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time this morning for a better example, but consider the following simple case:

```
public class Inner {
   public int IX {get;set;}
    public string IY {get;set;}
}

public class Outer {
    public int OX {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Inner> OI {get;set;}
}

public XDocument SerializeOuter(Outer obj)
{
    return new XDocument(
        new XElement("Outer",
            new XAttribute("OX", obj.OX.ToString()),
            new XElement("Inners", from i in obj.OI
                                   select SerializeInner(i))));
}

private XElement SerializeInner(Inner obj)
{
    return new XElement("Inner",
                        new XAttribute("IX", obj.IX),
                        new XElement("IY", obj.IY));
}
```

Example use:

```
public static void Demo()
{
    var outer = new Outer {
        OX = 1,
        OI = new[] {new Inner {IX = 2, IY = "two"}, new Inner {IX = 3, IY = "three"}}
    };

    var doc = SerializeOuter(outer);
    Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
}
```

This produces:

```
<Outer OX="1">
  <Inners>
    <Inner IX="2">
      <IY>two</IY>
    </Inner>
    <Inner IX="3">
      <IY>three</IY>
    </Inner>
  </Inners>
</Outer>
```

Comment: This is interessting to me, but how would you handle the multiple reference with this ?

Comment: Multiple references to the same object would have to be handled in your visiting logic.